# Where does nodejs store its variables?

Tags: node.js, variables, storage

I'm beginning with nodejs + expressjs. I wonder where does all these variables will be stored if i created it on the server?

For example, i declare this object and i add element to it. So this object is going to be bigger.
It still alive if webserver is still running.

```
var http = require("http");
var abc = {}

function start() {
    function onRequest(request,response) {
        console.log("request received")
        response.writeHead(200,{"Content-Type":"text/plain"})
        var id = ( Math.random() * 100000 ) | 0
        abc[id.toString()] = 1
        response.write(Object.keys(abc).length.toString());
        response.end();
    }
    http.createServer(onRequest).listen(8888)
    console.log("Server has started")
}

exports.start = start
```

Look at `abc` object, it will have one more element if you refresh the browser.

So how nodejs stores these variables?

Comment: In memory? Where does any code store its variables?

Comment: So, if i don't handle good the server may get into out of memory?

Comment: Sure, but... You'd have to work at it. It's like any code anywhere-you can always run out of memory (or thrash virtual memory until performance is terrible).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variables get stored in the memory itself. If the server stops for some reason. All the variable data present in the memory gets lost. If you want to retain that data. Better save it into some database.

Comment: Can a variable store `100MB` of data ? What is the size limitation for node js variable ?